# Data format confusion after changing version of Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have just moved from using Python 2.7.8 to 3.4.5  In the 2.7.8 version the following line of code run without issue and now using the 3.4.5 I get the exception :

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'dt'
```

The line is:

```
DeptTemplate['Status change date'].dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
```

Where I am reformatting the data-frame column '`Status change date`' to a date format

The only thing I have changed is the version of Python so I am assuming this is the issue.

I've tried to research the fix but am confused as to what I need to change.

Comment: what version of pandas are you using?

Comment: Mmm, this doesn't make sense. If anything, it's a pandas issue. What is the name of your script btw? I can't think of a pandas version where this behaviour changed, it seems there's something external causing this issue

Comment: Thanks. I think you might be right  version of pandas I'm using with 2.7.8 is 0.19.2 and the version of pandas I'm using with 3.4.5 is 0.14.1.  Is there a way to upgrade my pandas version using conda?

Comment: @Stacey it certainly is the version of pandas...you can do conda update

Comment: _how_ have you ended up with 0.14 version? It sounds like some dependency has trashed your installation on python 3. Thats way old! :) conda should not install that version.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comments above, the version of Python shouldn't make a difference here. The `dt` method is only available on datetime series. So the columns `'Status change date'` should already be a datetime before you use this method.

`.dt.strftime` does not convert a column to a datetime format. Rather it converts a datetime column to a string representation of a datetime